# I want to change register page url in laravel 5.3 from /register to /custom-register

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to change register page url in laravel 5.3 from /register to /custom-register

how can i hack(override) auth() function in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\router.php

Answer (score 1):

Altering a vendor file is not a good idea because the changes are not permanent, the next time you issue a `composer update` these files gets updated and you lose all your edits.

The way I would do this task is registering my custom routes instead of using `Auth::routes()` like this:

```
Route::get('/custom-register', ['as' => 'user.register', 'uses' => 'YourController@register']);
```

Comment: Yes i know that i do not want to play with laravel core, another thing i do not want to play with route.php, because i want another urls(login, forget password, reset ...) to be the same just i want to change the register page so i want to override the auth() function as mentioned above

Comment: It is not a bad thing to define routes, web.php and api.php are there just for that. There is no need to override the `auth` function in my opinion.

Comment: Oops, I hit enter by mistake: just wanted to add that you can take note of the original routes laravel uses and redefine them exactly the same and just change the register route.

Comment: why i need to add multi lines for that and Auth::routes();  do the same thing and make web.php more clear and cool!

Comment: I think there is a way to override that function or something like this

Comment: In my original answer I mentioned that you can add just two lines to the routes, the get and post methods for the custom registration and point them to the default laravel registration methods `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm` and `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register`. If you edit the auth() method you still have to declare the original routes if you want to use them, meaning two extra lines anyway. You can override the auth() method but you are still declaring routes even if you don't see them on the web.php file.

Comment: Still you can create your own version of  `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::routes` and use it on your routes file instead of the default one.